# How to find limit of the sequence given by $f_{n+1}=\frac{3}{7}f_n+8$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

> A sequence is defined by recurrence relation $f_{n+1}=\frac{3}{7}f_n+8$ with $\mu_0=-14$, then what is the limit of the sequence?

1. $14$
2. $-14$
3. $\frac{-3}{7}$
4. $\frac{3}{7}$

---

My attempt:

[As wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) :  the limit of a sequence is the value that the terms of a sequence "tend to". If such a limit exists, the sequence is called convergent.

I'm stuck here what is $\mu_0=-14$? How do I find limit of the sequence?

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: There's no context or explanation where the notation $\mu_0$ comes from? If the sequence converges to $L$, then $f_n \to L$ and $f_{n+1} \to L$ so you're looking for a number $L$ that satisfies $L  = \tfrac{3}{7}L+8$.

Comment: Note that for $f_{n+1} = 2f_n - 5$ similar reasoning would get $L=5$, but then convergence would depend on initial value $f_0$ ($\mu_0$?).

Comment: The general solution is $f_n=-28\cdot \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n+14$, thus: $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} f_n=14.$ Note: Because $\frac{3}{7}<1$ in both original recurrence relation and general solution, it is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mu_0$ is probably $f_0$, the first term of the sequence. As already said, if the limit exists ($\exists \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n = F$), then we can write $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n+1} = {3 \over 7}\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n + 8 \\
F = {3 \over 7}F + 8 \\
F = 14$$
The problem is with **if** part. There are several ways to prove that $f_n$ converges for any $f_0$, but the simplest would be to take
$$g_n = f_n-14, g_0 = f_0-14 = -28 \\
g_{n+1}+14 = {3 \over 7}(g_n+14) + 8 \\
g_{n+1} = {3 \over 7}g_n = ({3 \over 7})^2g_{n-1} = ... =  ({3 \over 7})^{n+1}g_0$$
Thus, $\exists \lim_{n \to \infty}g_n = 0$ and $\exists \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n = 14$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ if the limit exists.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You are welcome.